# MySQL Workbench Forward Engineer

Tags: mysql-workbench

I have my EERD setup exactly how I want it to be and I used forward engineering to upload the EERD to the database. I then did a reverse engineer on that database to see if the two EERD's matched. I found many of the relations between the tables were different.

How accurate do you think MySQL workbench is in regards to forward/reverse engineering? It is my first time using MySQL workbench to create a database so I want to double check its reliability.

Comment: Most of the reverse engineer problems stemmed from 0-Many relationships being turned into 1-Many relationships.

Also looks like not null doesn't show on the EERD properly at times.